# Invalid PBLK lenghth [7]

Tags: boot, 16.10

On booting, on black screen I have this message for a while (on every boot):

```
[      0.136664] acpi LNXCPU:00: Invalid PBLK length [7]
[      0.136699] acpi LNXCPU:01: Invalid PBLK length [7]
[      1.932099] tpm tpm0: A TPM error (7) occurred attemting to read a pcr value
/dev/sda5: clean, 649320/5857280 files, 16517369/23401472 blocks
```

Comment: I have this issue too. From what I searched, it is happening only on HP computers (like mine). Can you tell me if your computer is an HP ?